# python script executed from php won't read saved model

Tags: php, laravel

Here is what I'm trying to do: 
I'm sending an Ajax request with an image as data to a php script that uploads it and execute a python script with the image name the python script loads a gender detection model and predict the gender on the person on the image.

The problem is the model doesn't load, I tried it with the php and python script in the same directory and it worked fine but I'm trying to use it in laravel so I can't do that anymore.

when I try running the python script manually like that :

```
python path/to/script.py
```

It throws this error : `OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Unspecified error (File can't be opened for reading!)`

but when I do this it works:-

```
cd path/to/script.py ; python script.py
```

Here is my php:-

```
    $file = $this->upload_Image($request->get('image'));
    $path =public_path().'/app/Http/Controllers';
    $command='cd '.$path.';';
    $path= 'python '.$path.'/facifier.py '.storage_path('app').$file;

    $command .= $path;
    return exec($command);

    Storage::disk('local')->delete($file);
    return json_encode($orderedData);
```

The command ends up like this : `cd absolute/path/to/script.py ; python script.py absolute/path/to/image.jpg`
when I use it on a command prompt it works fine. 
Here is where I get the error on my python script:-

```
fisher_face_gender = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()
fisher_face_gender.read('models/gender_classifier_model_kdef.xml')
```

does anyone know whats causing this, I'm on windows by the way.

Comment: Make sure the working directory of your web server is what you expect (contains a models folder).

Comment: it does contain it, I think the problem is related to privilege of the python script since if it is executed from the same directory it works but when its executed from another directory it doesn't and the path is fine since everything before reading the model gets executed

Comment: `"models/gender_classifier_model_kdef.xml"` is __NOT__ an absolute path - it's relative to the current working directory.

Comment: Oh and yes: it's definitly not a Python question - your "gender detection script" could be written in just any language, the problem would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to bruno desthuilliers comment i got it working. The problem was in the path to model i used,its relative to the python script because i thought that the script executes on its own path not on the command promt's path .

I just changed the path to the model to the absolute path and it worked fine